# Ещё одна задача на javascript

Tags: javascript

Итак, есть выпадающий список:

```
<form name="sel">
    <select name="navsel" onChange="selects(this)">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Он определяет номер строки.

```
var sele = document.forms.sel.navsel.value;
var elm=document.all(sele);
```

Переменная elm есть все элементы страницы.
Задача: сделать функцию, которая берёт значение sele, подставляет в elm, получает результат информации о строке в таком виде [object HTMLHtmlElement], и при помощи switch выводить нормальные данные:

```
switch(elm) {
    case '[object HTMLHtmlElement]' : elm = '<html>' 
    break
    case '[object HTMLHeadElement]' : elm = '<head>' 
    break
}
document.writeln("Выбранный элемент страницы - "+elm+" Номер элемента - "+sele);
```

Ну и, конечно же, чтобы всё было динамично, при изменении значения списка тут же выводилась новая информация о строке и её номере.
В данный момент функция выглядит так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selects() {
    var sele = document.forms.sel.navsel.value;
    var elm=document.all(sele);
    switch(elm) {
        case '[object HTMLHtmlElement]' : elm = '<html>' 
        break
        case '[object HTMLHeadElement]' : elm = '<head>' 
        break
        case '[object HTMLMetaElement]' : elm = '<meta>'
        break
    }
    document.writeln("Выбранный элемент страницы - "+elm+" Номер элемента - "+sele);
}
</script>
```

Но после изменения значения списка форма пропадает, а switch не работает, то есть [object HTMLHtmlElement] не меняется на

```
<html>
```

Что я упустил?

Comment: @chuikoff Уважаемый участник, поскольку формат форума допускает только один вопрос в теме (иначе тема запутывается) я удалил ваш вопрос в форме ответа (преобразовать в комментарий его не удалось). Если Вы хотите уточнить ответ, пожалуйста, сделайте краткий комментарий-вопрос к ответу или откройте новую тему.

Comment: Комментарии оформлены очень нечитабельно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Bokiv">
<meta name="generator" content="AceHTML 6 Pro">  
<script type="text/javascript">
function selects() {
    var sele = document.forms.sel.navsel.value; 
    var elm=document.all[sele].tagName;

    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML +=
        "Выбранный элемент страницы - " + elm + " Номер элемента - " + sele;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="sel">
    <select name="navsel" onchange="selects()"> 
        <option>Выбрать:</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>     
<div id="results"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

case тут не нужен!

Comment: Наконец то вставил ))

Comment: Спасибо! Вопросов нет, решение оказалось таким простым)

Comment: Если, что обращайся всегда буду рад помочь))

Answer (score 1):

Если вызывать методы document.write()/writeln() после загрузки страницы (как у вас), то это затрёт всё её содержимое. Пользуйтесь innerHTML:

```
<div id="results"></div>

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += 'Your text<br>';
```

Comment: Спасибо. А почему switch не работает?